# How to send variable value into an API using Flutter and Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to send variable value to an API for getting user details (for that particular user after login only)

Here is the code i am using (just trying to send that uid into the api link):

```html
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
getCurrentUser() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
  final uid = user.uid;
  print(uid);
}

Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {
  var data = await http.get("https://api.example.com/get/myuserid=$uid");
  var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
  List<User> users = [];
  for (var u in jsonData) {
    User user = User(u["customer_id"]]);
    users.add(user);
  }
  print(users.length);
  return users;
}
```

But i am getting this error:
ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(210)] Dart Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use _getUsers like that;

```
  Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {
final response = await http.get("https://api.example.com/get/myuserid=$uid");
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return json.decode(response.body);
} else {
  throw Exception("error");
}
```

}
And, you can use _getUser() in the FutureBuilder to access your data like that;

```
FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
          future: _getUsers(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                   snapshot.data.customer_id
```

But now, you can't use customer_id in this way.Before using customer_id, You should map your all data to use as a key

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not in sending the UID in API its working fine ,
the problem is in

```
for (var u in jsonData) {
    User user = User(u["customer_id"]]);
    users.add(user);
  }
```

jsonData is a `Map<String, dynamic>` you can't use for loop like that in map

Comment: you mean the loop is woking fine??

Comment: after adding the uid variable value, i am getting this error

Comment: didn't get you but this error ` type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable`  appears when we are trying to use a Map in place of a Iterable

Comment: could you include what you are getting in jsonData??

Comment: in the api
if i am using it like this: https://api.example.com/get/myuserid=test

then i am getting everything perfect,
but when i am trying to send uid as a variable value like this:
https://api.example.com/get/myuserid=$uid

that error appears

Comment: is `uid` is a global variable ?? in code its only present in getCurrentUsers() , are you sure you are getting uid in _getUsers()??

Comment: ok, How to set a variable value as global in Flutter??

Comment: I tried few methods, but i was not able to make it as global.